# Python split lines from read file and write them with another format in another file

Tags: python, csv, split

I read the lines from a file which containing two columns with values in that style:

```
      100.E-03             5.65581E-06
      110.E-03            11.222E-06  
      120.E-03            18.3487E-06 
      130.E-03            15.6892E-06
```

I need to write them in antoher file as:

```
          100.E-03       ,      5.65581E-06
          110.E-03       ,     11.222E-06  
          120.E-03       ,     18.3487E-06 
          130.E-03       ,     15.6892E-06
```

Can I do this with split? Can I define spaces, for example 5 spaces as the split variable? And when yes, how can I pick the splitted parts in order to write them in the way I want:
My script looks like:

```
for k in files:
    print 'k =',k
    from  abaqus import session
    print k 
    with open("niffacc{k}.inp".format(k=k)) as f1:
       with open("niffacc_{k}.inp".format(k=k),"w") as f2:
            for line in itertools.islice(f1, 4, None):
                b = line.split("            ")
                #print "b:", b
                c = b[1]
                d = b[3] 
                f2.write('%s'%c + "," + '%s'%d)    
    #with open('VY_{k}'.format(k=k), 'a') as f1:
    #lines = f1.readlines()
    f2.close()
    f1.close()
```

I think the problem is in defining b, the splitted line. Is there any problem by defining as split character the spaces? Does python have a problem ti split because of the many spaces or it is handled as a groups of spaces?
Is a better solution to convert the file in csv file and then back to txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want that many spaces between your columns but you can just split on whitespace:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        f2.write(line.split()[0] + ',' + line.split()[1] + '\n')
```

If you really want a bunch of spaces, then just use:

```
f2.write(line.split()[0] + '    ,    ' + line.split()[1] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` will automatically deal with any number of spaces.

```
'      100.E-03             5.65581E-06'.split() == ['100.E-03', '5.65581E-06']
```